# eCharts: how to access chart from tooltip formatter function

Tags: echarts

I need to access the chart (echarts 5.0.0) on which the tooltip ist shown from inside the tooltip formatter function. How can I access it?

```
let chartOption = {
//... all the other stuff
        tooltip: {
            //...
            formatter: function (params, ticket, callback) {
              //how to access chart when formatter function is called?
            }
        },
//... more stuff
};
let chart = echarts.init(document.getElementById("myChart"));
chart.setOption(chartOption);
```

Comment: By using the `chart` instance?

Comment: Please Answer the Question, if you know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this by getting the charts id from mouse position:

```
let elements = document.querySelectorAll( ":hover" );
let chartId = elements.item(elements.length -1).parentElement.parentElement.id;
let chart = charts[chartId];
```

where "charts" holds all the chart instances on the page with the id of the div as key.

Answer (score 0):

```
let chartOption = {
//... all the other stuff
        tooltip: {
            //...
            formatter: function (params, ticket, callback) {
                chart.xxx
            }
        },
//... more stuff
};
let chart = echarts.init(document.getElementById("myChart"));
chart.setOption(chartOption);
```

But I'm not sure what you want to do with the chart instance because in most cases you don't have to.

Comment: The Question is: how to access the chart instance from inside the tooltip formatter function. And no, the answers is not: use the chart instance. I'm also not interested in the cases where I don't need to access the charts instance, because this is a case where I want to access the chart instance.